# How to solve XAudio2.9 virtual audio device problem?

Tags: c++, directx

Could someone answer my question, please?

I develop an application with XAudio2.9 on Windows 10.
I connect and disconect an USB headset while the app is running.
Rarely, but sometimes I see errors on the debug console, for example:

*avcore\audiocore\client\audioclient\audioclientcore.cpp(1484)\AUDIOSES.DLL!00007FFE70E24FF9: (caller: 00007FFE70E020FD) ReturnHr(2) tid(5c5c) 88890004 The thread 0x4c4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x22f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
avcore\audiocore\client\audioclient\audioclientclock.cpp(78)\AUDIOSES.DLL!00007FFE70E2365B: (caller: 00007FFE70E20321) ReturnHr(1) tid(5efc) 88890004 avcore\audiocore\client\audioclient\audioclientclock.cpp(78)\AUDIOSES.DLL!00007FFE70E2365B: (caller: 00007FFE70E20321) ReturnHr(2) tid(5efc) 88890004 avcore\audiocore\client\audioclient\audioclientcore.cpp(1484)\AUDIOSES.DLL!00007FFE70E24FF9: (caller: 00007FFE70E020FD) ReturnHr(3) tid(5efc) 88890004 The thread 0x4d58 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
avcore\audiocore\client\audioclient\audioclientclock.cpp(78)\AUDIOSES.DLL!00007FFE70E2365B: (caller: 00007FFE70E20321) ReturnHr(3) tid(5e08) 88890004 The thread 0x3ea8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
avcore\audiocore\client\audioclient\audioclientclock.cpp(78)\AUDIOSES.DLL!00007FFE70E2365B: (caller: 00007FFE70E20321) ReturnHr(4) tid(5e08) 88890004 The thread 0x4244 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
avcore\audiocore\client\audioclient\audioclientclock.cpp(78)\AUDIOSES.DLL!00007FFE70E2365B: (caller: 00007FFE70E20321) ReturnHr(5) tid(5e08) 88890004 avcore\audiocore\client\audioclient\audioclientclock.cpp(78)\AUDIOSES.DLL!00007FFE70E2365B: (caller: 00007FFE70E20321) ReturnHr(6) tid(5e08) 88890004 avcore\audiocore\client\audioclient\audioclientcore.cpp(1484)\AUDIOSES.DLL!00007FFE70E24FF9: (caller: 00007FFE70E020FD) ReturnHr(7) tid(5e08) 88890004 The thread 0x41b0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).*

What would be wrong?

Comment: Is there any actual problem with the audio when this happens? Do you get an OnCriticalError notification? If you use the default device for the Mastering Voice, XAudio 2.9 is using the WASAPI virtual audio support on Windows 10 unless you use ``AUDIO2_NO_VIRTUAL_AUDIO_CLIENT``. That debug output is coming from WASAPI, *not* XAudio2.

Comment: Thank you.
AUDIO2_NO_VIRTUAL_AUDIO_CLIENT + IMMNotificationClient work fine.
I will test more with OnCriticalError .